# How to send only application log to AWS S3 using FluentBit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-eks, fluent-bit

I have APIs (Fast API) that are deployed on EKS Cluster. I want to log the **Request** and **Response** Payload of the API into **AWS S3** using **FluentBit**.

Currently, FluentBit is sending all the detailed logs (all PODs logs) to AWS S3,

**Is there any way to send only API Code/application logs to AWS S3 instead complete EKS Cluster Logs using FluentBit?**

I don't want to write a pipeline to parse application logs from AWS S3. I am looking for an optimized way.